# Как получить большой файл с сервера, или почему браузер загружает, а мой .exe нет?

Tags: c#, .net, http, веб-сервер

Разместила на сервере файл. Пытаюсь получить его байты таким образом:

```
private static byte[] DownloadData(string url)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    return client.DownloadData(url);
}
```

В результате получения файла вылетает Exception: `The operation has time out`. Через браузер по этому же URL файл загружается. Были предположения по тому, что на сервере стоят какие-то ограничения на выдачу файла (или ограничение по максимальному размеру, или по времени сессии). Разбила файл на пакеты (на несколько файлов) и загружаю последовательно. Всё равно иногда не догружается всё до конца. Почему браузер загружает файл, а моё ПО нет? Что делать чтобы моё ПО могло загрузить большой файл? Проблема в настройках сервера, или я не учла какой-то параметр запроса на стороне клиента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас скорее всего срабатывает таймаут клиента. Чтобы его поменять, вам надо создать класс, унаследованный от WebClient

```
private class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        WebRequest w = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        w.Timeout = 20 * 60 * 1000; // Ваше значение Timeout
        return w;
    }
}
```

И использовать его.

```
private static byte[] DownloadData(string url)
{
    using(var client = new MyWebClient())
        return client.DownloadData(url);
}
```

(ответ по мотивам [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6994391/312041))

Ну, или можете использовать рекомендуемый способ для отправки веб запросов ([HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) + асинхронный запрос)

```
private static async Task<byte[]> DownloadData(string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        return await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. На localhost нормально работало. Значение timeout поставила на 60 часов (60 * 60 * 60 * 1000).  При загрузке с удалённого сервера иногда приходил повреждённый файл (архив выдавал ошибку при попытке расархивации). Заменила DownloadData на DownloadFile, чтобы файл сразу загружался в файловую систему. В итоге загружается только часть файла без каких-либо exception-ов. Метод асинхронной загрузки тоже пробовала. Есть ещё какие-то способы загрузки больших файлов с сервера. Или нужно их вручную разбивать на пакеты и загружать этими пакетами?